# Determinant of matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n,n}$

Tags: matrices, determinant

How to prove that for matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n,n}$ we have
$$\det A = \det
\begin{vmatrix}
x & x& x& ...&x&x\\ 
 1-x&  1&1 & ...&1& 1\\ 
 0&  1-x&  1& ...&1&1\\
0&  0&1-x&   ...&1&1\\
&&\ldots&& \\ 
0&  0&  0& ...&1-x&1\\
\end{vmatrix} =x^n
$$

Answer (score 3):

Subtract every column other than the last by the last column. Then move the last column to the first (this gives you a factor of $(-1)^{n-1}$ in the determinant). The result is a lower triangular matrix whose main diagonal is $(x,-x,-x,\ldots,-x)$. Thus the determinant of the original matrix is $(-1)^{n-1}x(-x)^{n-1}=x^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Let the determinant of $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be a polynomial in $x$ denoted as $P_n(x); P_1(x)=\det[x]=x$. Expand along the first column,

$\det A=P_n(x)=
\begin{vmatrix}
x& x & x & \ldots & x& x \\
1-x & 1 & 1&\ldots &1& 1 \\  
0 & 1-x & 1 & \ldots &1& 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1-x & \ldots &1& 1 \\ 
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots&\vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots&1-x&1 \notag
\end{vmatrix}_{n}\\=x\begin{vmatrix}
1& 1 &\ldots&1 \\
1-x & 1&\ldots &1\\  
0 & 1-x& \ldots &1\\ 
0 & 0& \ldots &1\\ 
\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\
0 & 0& \ldots&1-x\notag
\end{vmatrix}_{n-1}+(x-1)\begin{vmatrix}
x& x&\ldots & x\\
1-x & 1&\ldots &1\\  
0 & 1-x& \ldots &1\\ 
0 & 0& \ldots &1\\ 
\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\
0 & 0 & \ldots&1-x\notag
\end{vmatrix}_{n-1}$

Note that the first determinant is just $\frac {P_{n-1}(x)}x$ and the second one $P_{n-1}(x)$.

$\implies P_n(x)=x\cdot\frac{P_{n-1}(x)}x+(x-1)P_{n-1}(x)\\\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ =xP_{n-1}(x)\\\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ =x^2P_{n-2}(x)\\\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ =x^3P_{n-3}(x)\\\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ =x^{n-1}P_{n-(n-1)}(x)\\\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ =x^n$